How to get the index of duplicate elements along with the range of empty elements after it. LINQ
Dim ComplexArray As String() = Split("A   C  A     B   C   A B  A  B    C")

Dim Need_result= {({"A", ({"0-2", "5-9", "16-16", "19-20"})}), ({"B", ({"10-12", "17-18", "21-24"})}), ({"C", ({"3-4", "13-15", "25-25"})})}

When we copy vertically merged cells in Excel, such an array is obtained.(ComplexArray)
trying to get
The number of duplicates in the column where the cells are randomly merged, then the difference between the rows of the duplicates and z-a Descending of the duplicate cell


What is the type of the expected result? A Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Int32))?

hi Type is String

It's not for us to simply write your code for you. Put some effort into the problem for yourself and then ask for help if you encounter an actual issue. Start by working out the logic - how would you do it manually - which takes no programming experience at all. Once you have logic that works on various manual examples, you can write corresponding pseudo-code, then implement that in real code. If you encounter an issue at the implementation phase, then you have a question to ask us.

This was a question for me. I also posted the question. If I had known, I would not have posted the question. How do you think I can get the answer?

There is really no one to help me. I asked after ten months, but you said no to me. If this is the logic of humanity, don't let it.

Please explain how the expect result relates to the input ("obvious" is always in the eye of the beholder).

1 In the first step, unify the input array and keep it in the new array. Next..in the iteration loop, check the element of the new array with the original array (when the value is reached, then remove the first index..go forward until the next values are empty. Save the first index and the second index as strings .)

I suggest at least trying this with simple loop(s), then ask for help on how to implement it in LINQ. Request for code without showing your effort is not usual in SO.

@MansourDalir What do you mean by a 3D array? Inexperienced programmers often use the wrong name for data structures until they find out the correct terminology: the needResult line in your question is not valid code in VB.NET, so we can't find out from that. Perhaps we could work out what you need if you tell us how you are going to use the result.

@AndrewMorton with Option Strict Off, that is an Object()(). He wants a jagged array.

@MansourDalir your resulting data structure is an array of objects. In each column you have a string and an array of strings. Using a Dictionary(Of String, String()) would be a much more manageable data structure. The difficulty in obtaining your desired one leads to you not getting the answers you want - add that nobody would expect to use something like that. Also you have a jagged array, not a 3D (or 2D as it would be) multidimensional array.

@djv Do you think the OP would be better off with a structure (something) like List(Of Char, List(Of Range)) where Range is a class with First and Last properties? (I've already made a solution that works that way, but if they won't accept it there's no point posting it.)

@AndrewMorton I can see it. Your guess is as good as mine. I think most people here have the urge to convince OP not to use this data structure.

By obtaining this question, you can get and delete the range of duplicate cell addresses in Excel. Because in normal mode, it is not possible to delete duplicate rows in a merged manner. We need an array object that has an array of strings and a string.

There is an answer to a question close to this question. But it needs to be edited.If you think it's okay for me to post the answer?

First of all, you mention 3D array, which hints at multidimensional. From the look of your question only 2D is required. This is just a terminology issue. However, from the look of your data, a multidimensional array will not work, as each letter could have a different number of results. A multidimensional array [n,m] will have n rows and m columns, so this will not work for you. I guess you are looking for a jagged array [n][m] in which m can vary for each n. It's an important distinction, from which stems your frustration with the community.
Looking at your need,
'Option Strict Off

Dim Need_result = {({"A", ({"0-2", "5-9", "16-16", "19-20"})}), ({"B", ({"10-12", "17-18", "21-24"})}), ({"C", ({"3-4", "13-15", "25-25"})})}


I'm not going to bother with that data structure, sorry.
I recommend you use a Dictionary. At least, since you asked for LINQ, I will make a one-liner in LINQ to produce the dictionary.
Dim s = "A   C  A     B   C   A B  A  B    C"

Dim r = s.Split(" "c).Select(Function(c, i) New Tuple(Of String, Integer)(c, i)).
        Where(Function(t) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Item1)).
        Select(Function(t) (t.Item1, $"{t.Item2}-{t.Item2 + s.Split(" "c).Skip(t.Item2 + 1).TakeWhile(Function(c) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c)).Count()}")).
        GroupBy(Function(t) t.Item1).
        Select(Function(g) (g.Key, g.Select(Function(t) t.Item2).ToArray())).
        OrderBy(Function(t) t.Key).
        ToDictionary(Function(kvp) kvp.Key, Function(kvp) kvp.ToArray)

In multiple lines:
Dim r1 = s.Split(" "c).Select(Function(c, i) New Tuple(Of String, Integer)(c, i))
Dim r2 = r1.Where(Function(t) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Item1))
Dim r3 = r2.Select(Function(t) (t.Item1, $"{t.Item2}-{t.Item2 + s.Split(" "c).Skip(t.Item2 + 1).TakeWhile(Function(c) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c)).Count()}"))
Dim r4 = r3.GroupBy(Function(t) t.Item1)
Dim r5 = r4.Select(Function(g) (g.Key, g.Select(Function(t) t.Item2).ToArray()))
Dim r6 = r5.OrderBy(Function(t) t.Key)
Dim r7 = r6.ToDictionary(Function(kvp) kvp.Key, Function(kvp) kvp.ToArray)

Let's see the output
For Each k In r.Keys
    Debug.Print($"{k}: {String.Join(", ", r(k))}")
Next


A: 0-2, 5-9, 16-16, 19-20
B: 10-12, 17-18, 21-24
 C: 3-4, 13-15, 25-25

Now compare the output with your Need_result,

It's the same data, with the added benefit of type-safety and the ability to key the data structure.
What if you want to know how many "B" ranges there are?
' using Object()()
Dim y = DirectCast(Need_result(Array.FindIndex(Need_result, Function(n) n(0).ToString() = "B"))(1), String()).Count()

' using Dictionary(String, String())
Dim z = r("B").Length


Error BC30518 I don't know why it gives an error. on (.Select) - ver vs2019

@MansourDalir see the edit, on which line are you getting the error?

Dim r1 = s.Split(" "c).Select(Function(c, i) (c, i))   'this Part '.Select'

@MansourDalir The "error" is because VS is using a version of VB too early to work with that syntax (it needs to be able to use the implied names of members of anonymous types). You can fix it with the simple change shown in Select the Visual Basic language version. N.B. Make sure to save your work before you make the change.

@MansourDalir I changed the answer to use  a typed tuple, try it now

Hello. It still has an error. I posted the error image

@MansourDalir it doesn't make sense to edit your question with that image. I'll roll back. The image you mentioned is linked here. It shows a "ValueTuple", which I am not using. Check your code.

@djv It needs three more alterations to work with pre-15.3 VB: Dim r5 = r4.Select(Function(g) New Tuple(Of String, String())(g.Key, g.Select(Function(t) t.Item2).ToArray())), Dim r6 = r5.OrderBy(Function(t) t.Item1), and Dim r7 = r6.ToDictionary(Function(kvp) kvp.Item1, Function(kvp) kvp.Item2.ToArray()).

@AndrewMorton And Dim r3 = r2.Select(Function(t) New Tuple(Of String, String)(t.Item1, $"{t.Item2}-{t.Item2 + s.Split(" "c).Skip(t.Item2 + 1).TakeWhile(Function(c) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c)).Count()}"))   fixed. thank

I just wish I had a reputation for rating. If possible, suggest what I should do to increase my reputation. Thank you for the forum

@djv If possible, give the final edit of the answer code. Thank you

@djv In Excel, when I copy the column whose cells are more or less merged and give its array to your code, the answer is still negative. My data is in a text file, how can I put it here?

Trying for this file Data.txt

    Dim ComplexArray As String() = Split("A   C  A     B   C   A B  A  B    C")
    Dim resultArray = ComplexArray.
Select(Function(word, index) New With {.Word = word, .Index = index}).
GroupBy(Function(x) x.Word).
Select(Function(g) New Object() {
    g.Key,
    g.Select(Function(x) x.Index).
        Select(Function(index, i) New With {.Index = index, .Diff = If(i = 0, 0, index - g.ElementAt(i - 1).Index - 1)}).
        Select(Function(x) $"{x.Index}-{x.Index + x.Diff}").
        ToArray()
}).
ToArray()


Similar to the result

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
